# Word to describe a container for intangible assets

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

If you had a box that held individual experiences what would you call it?

- These experiences do not necessarily have to be your own.
- Others can put their own experiences in the box.
- The experiences are all related by physical location.
- You can only view the experiences when you are physically near the
  box.

What would you call this box? A container? A vault? A vessel?

Comment: a *pensieve* ?? ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps a **[repository](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/repository?q=repository)**

> a person or thing regarded as a store of information or in which something abstract is held to exist or be found

**SUPPLEMENT**

Also maybe **[trove](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/trove?q=trove)**

> a store of valuable or delightful things

Or **[treasury](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/treasury?q=treasury)**

> a store or collection of valuable or delightful things

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, something along these lines. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I would call it a 'Life Capsule', to correspond with a 'Time Capsule'.

Comment: Do you have any ideas on something that's only word and little more generic?